# What is the locus when the radius is cut to its projection?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, locus

> Fix a circle $\bigcirc O$ and a diameter $d$.  For each point $A$ on $\bigcirc O$, let $A'$ be its projection onto $d$, and mark $\Lambda$ on ray $OA$ such that $O\Lambda \cong AA'$.  What is the locus of all such points $\Lambda$?
>
> Source: Hadamard's *Geometry*

My proof is below, to which I request verification, critique, or alternatives.

**Solution:** Let diameter $d'$ be perpendicular to $d$, and mark the intersections of $d'$ with $\bigcirc O$ as $Y$ and $Y'$.   Then the desired locus is the two circles $\omega, \omega'$ with diameters $OY$ and $OY'$.

[image]

**Proof (Synthetic):**
Suppose $A$ is on the same side of $d$ as $Y$.  Then we have $$O\Lambda \cong AA' \text{ (by construction)} \\
OY \cong OA \text{ (as both are radii of} \bigcirc O \text{)} \\
\angle \Lambda O Y \cong \angle A'AO \text{ (since } OY \parallel A'A\text{)}$$ so by SAS $$\triangle OY\Lambda \cong \triangle AOA'$$ and $\angle O \Lambda Y$ is a right angle.

Then by Thales' Theorem, $\Lambda$ is on circle $\omega$.

A similar argument shows that when $A$ is on the other side of $d$ then $\Lambda$ is on $\omega'$.

Conversely, if $\Lambda$ is any point on $\omega$, then by AAS,  $\triangle OY\Lambda \cong \triangle AOA'$, so  $O  \Lambda \cong AA'$, completing the proof.

**Proof (Analytic):** Using $O$ as our origin, the desired locus clearly has the equation $$r = |\sin \theta|$$ for $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$. The circle $\omega$ has the equation $$\sqrt{(r\cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta - \frac 1 2)^2} = \frac 1 2$$  for $r \geq 0, \theta \in [0,  \pi]$, which simplifies to $$%\sqrt{r^2\cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta -r\sin \theta + \frac 1 4} = \frac 1 2\\
\sqrt{r^2 -r\sin \theta + \frac 1 4} = \frac 1 2$$ and is clearly met if and only if $r = | \sin \theta|$ and $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.  A similar argument applies to $\omega'$ when $\theta \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, completing the proof.

Comment: Please change your diagram to include *all* the points you refer to, and also so that OΛ≅OA′ is at least nearly true. [In your diagram these two segments are nowhere near  the same length]

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for catching that - the diagram is good, but there was a typo in the problem, which I've fixed.  All referenced points are in the diagram.  The diameter $d$ and its perp $d'$ are drawn but not labelled (as they're self-explanatory).